# How to see why Event ID 4800/4801 are logging

Tags: security, logging, events, locking, unlock

Hey guys so I was having trouble understanding why the lock/unlocks are being logged on a computer. I checked the gpedit for "Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events" and see it as "Not configured" and another computer is "Configured" but with Success/Failure not checked. They are both logging 4800 and 4801 events. I was trying to see why that would be and if there was a registry key that would be the actual area that Windows OS would check to log the events. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps Server Fault would be a better place to ask?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.